# how to specialize template taking any type to allow variable length arrays

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

Not even sure what the right terminology for this situation is.  If I knew it then I probably would have found the answer.

I have a templatized function that looks like

```
template<typename T> void write(Buffer& b, const T& value);
```

There is no generic implementations of this, only explicit specializations.  E.g.

```
template<> void write<int>(Buffer& b, const int& value) { ... }
template<> void write<const char *>(Buffer& b, const char * const & value) { ... }
```

So far so good.  But of course when I call as `write(buffer, "hello")` I get a link error complaining

```
undefined reference to `void write<char [6]>(Buffer&, char const (&) [6])'
```

This error makes sense to me.  But what I cannot figure out is how to declare a specialization for this.  All I want such a specialization to do is cast the `char[]` argument to `(const char*)` and call that existing specialization.  But I cannot figure out how to do this.

For the specific example I can do

```
template<size_t N> void write<char[6]>(Buffer& b, char const (&value) [6])
```

but it's obviously not acceptable to define one of these for every possible length string constant.  But I've tried the following, some of which are just grasping for straws, and none of which work.

```
template<size_t N> void write<char const[N]>(Buffer& ob, char const (&value) [N])
template<size_t N> template<> void write<char const[N]>(Buffer& ob, char const (&value) [N])
template<> template<size_t N> void write<char const[N]>(Buffer& ob, char const (&value) [N])
template<template<size_t N>> void write<char const[N]>(Buffer& ob, char const (&value) [N])
```

What's the proper incantation?  I'm using GCC 4.7.3 x86_64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do partial specialization of template functions. See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973040/specialize-a-void-function-template-to-a-const-charn) for how to do a level of indirection to a function in a templated class in order to get around this limitation.

In this simple case you could also get by with a non-template `write` that invokes the template one:

```
void write(Buffer &b), const char *v)
{
    write<const char *>(b, v);
}
```

This effectively hides the cast that would have worked with your template function in an inline function.

Comment: @SnoopyLane - did this answer the question?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply.  Lots of distractions.  Indeed, this did explain the problem, and the non-template version is what I ended up with.  Non-template is what I originally wanted, but I got distracted deep in some metaprogramming and thought I _needed_ the templates.  The snippets that I pasted at the top had simplified that away.

Answer (score 1):

If it is OK, not to specify the argument type when calling the `write()` function with a character array (or to use `char const*` in these cases rather than, e.g., `char[6]`), the way to implement this is to use an overload to deal with `char const*`:

```
void write(Buffer& ob, char const* value) {
    write<char const*>(ob, value);
}
```

This function is preferred over the template instantiations and can, thus, be used to suitably delegate the processing for string literals (or C-strings in general, actually).

If it is necessary to get the correct type passed, the only way which would work is to not specialize the actual function template but, instead, to immediately delegate a `struct` with a suitable member function and to partially specialize this `struct` to deal with arrays: you cannot partially specialize a function template, i.e., the following is illegal:

```
template <int N>
void write<char const[N]>(Buffer& ob, char const (&value)[N]); // ERROR
```

... but it can be simulated by partially specializing a `struct` instead.

Comment: Thanks Deitmar.  Sorry for the very late reply.  So what do you mean by "simulated by partially specializing a struct instead"?  Got a link to an example?

Comment: What I mean, is to wrap the function into a partially specialized `struct`, i.e., `template <typename> struct helper; template <int N> struct helper<char const[N]> { static void write(Buffer& obj, char const (&value)[N]); };`